# Node connect to a Xmpp Server in localhost

Tags: node.js, xmpp

I'm trying to connect with node to a local openfire server using the node-xmpp-client package.

```
npm install node-xmpp-client
```

I've configurated the server and i've created a user test1 with password: 'password' and email: 'test1@email.it'

This is my client.js file

```
var request = require('request');
var util = require('util');
var Client = require('node-xmpp-client');


var client = new Client({
  jid: //?
  password: "password",
});

client.on('online', function(){
  console.log('online');
});
```

I don't really get what i should insert in the jid variable.

Someone has faced a similar situation? Thanks in advance for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jid` stands for "Jabber ID" - an identification of an `XMPP` client.

In your case the string `"test1@email.it"` should work. It may also include so called resource (as several clients may be registered to the same account in dialogs there may be a need to address specific device).

With an optional resource string `JID` looks like `"test1@email.it/myclient"`.